# Knockout multilpe arrays not populating

Tags: knockout.js

Trying to learn knockout and got stopped cold with my first test.
In the example below the second select never populates. 
I can change them around with the same result.
I am currently reading the documentation and have searched a number of sites with no resolution.
I must be missing something, here is a simple example of my issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../knockout.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<select data-bind="options: letters, value: letter, optionsText: 'letter'"></select>
<select data-bind="options: numbers, value: number, optionsText: 'number'"></select>  

<script type="text/javascript">

function testViewModel() {

var self = this;
self.letters = [
    { letter: "A" }, { letter: "B"}, { letter: "C"}, { letter: "D" }, { letter: "E"}, 
    { letter: "F"}, { letter: "G"}];

self.numbers =  [
    { number: "1" }, { number: "2"}, { number: "3"}, { number: "4" }, { number: "5"}, 
    { number: "6"}, { number: "7"}];

}

$(document).ready(function(){
ko.applyBindings(new testViewModel());
});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the `optionsText` setting, the `value` setting requires the name of a property so it has to be wrapped in quotes.  Try this:

```
<select data-bind="options: letters, value: 'letter', optionsText: 'letter'"></select>
<select data-bind="options: numbers, value: 'number', optionsText: 'number'"></select>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your time and efforts! Still not sure why it populated the first, should it not have populated anything?